# Absolute value of hyperbolic function

Tags: complex-numbers, hyperbolic-functions

Is this statement true, if yes, can anyone show me why?

$$
\cosh(z)\cosh(z^*) = |\cosh(z)|^2
$$

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that $ww^\ast = |w|^2$ for every $w \in \Bbb C$, right? Just note that: $$\cosh(z^\ast) = \frac{e^{z^\ast}+ e^{-z^\ast}}{2} = \frac{(e^z)^\ast + (e^{-z})^\ast}{2} = \left(\frac{e^z+e^{-z}}{2}\right)^\ast = \cosh(z)^\ast,$$ since: $$e^{(x+iy)^\ast}=e^{x-iy} = e^x(\cos (-y) + i \sin(-y)) = e^x(\cos y - i \sin y) = (e^{x+iy})^\ast.$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $Z Z^*=|Z|^2$, by choosing $Z=\cosh z$ all you need to show is that $\cosh (z^*)=(\cosh z)^*$ which is true. Let $z= x+i y$, where $x,y$ are reals and $i$ is imaginary unit,  then
$$
(e^{x+iy})^*=e^x(\cos y + i\sin y)^*=e^x(\cos y - i\sin y)=e^x(\cos(- y) + i\sin (-y))=e^{x-iy}
$$
and therefore
$$(\cosh z)^* =\left( \frac{e^{x+iy} + e^{-(x+iy)}}{2}\right)^*= 
\frac{(e^{x+iy})^* + (e^{-(x+iy)})^*}{2}
= \frac{e^{x-iy} + e^{-(x-iy)}}{2} = \cosh(z^*)
$$

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is any entire function such that $f(x)$ is real for all real $x$, then $f(\bar z) = \overline{f(z)}$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

(Let $g(z) = \overline{f(\bar z)}$. Then $g$ is entire, and $g = f$ on the real axis, and thus by the identity principle everyhere.)

In particular $f(z)f(\bar z) = |f(z)|^2$, and $\cosh$ is entire (and real valued on the real axis).